# Java convert .obj to OpenGL for Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have a Blender .obj-file which gets uploaded to a tomcat webserver.

Now I need to convert and store this file into an Oracle database.

The converted data should be usable by an Android OpenGL Viewer (I don't implement that Android app, so I can't change the way it gets its data), who gets its data somehow from the database.

My question is: how can I convert the .obj-file into something that the OpenGL Viewer will understand and store it to the database?

Answer (score 0):

I've previously recommended [ObjImport](http://www.pixelnerve.com/processing/libraries/objimport/) from Pixel Nerve for this kind of work. Note that this tool is really just a parse, and you still have to write a ton of code in order to get it to do something useful.

There is another option which I have not used but I have heard good things about - [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/introduction/) actually integrates with OpenGL. You still have to write quite a bit of code but its closer to the goal post, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just dump the OBJ file into a SQL schema that can represent vertices, faces and a list of faces. For example

```
CREATE TABLE vertices (object_ID KEY, vert_ID INTEGER, x DOUBLE, y DOUBLE, z DOUBLE);
CREATE TABLE faces(object_ID KEY, vertex_A INTEGER, vertex_B INTEGER, vertex_C INTEGER);
```

Then to load your object to OpenGL

```
SELECT x,y,z FROM vertices WHERE objectID = ... ORDER BY vert_ID;
```

and put the result into a vertex array. Similar for the faces

```
SELECT vertex_A, vertex_B, vertex_C FROM faces WHERE objectID = ...;
```

and use the resulting array for calling `glDrawElements`

If you don't know how to use vertex arrays and glDrawElements, then first learn their use, so that you know how to use the result of a SQL dump for drawing.